SQL query to fetch org level data
I need to derive a few fields based on below input data. I have 2 input tables:
Table 1:



badge
l1_mgr_id
l2_mgr_id
l3_mgr_id
l4_mgr_id
l1_mgr_name
l2_mgr_name
l3_mgr_name
l4_mgr_name
cost_center




12
888
777
666
555
A
B
C
D
123


666
444
333
222
111
E
F
G
H
125


555
900
800
700
600
I
J
K
L
127


222
38
48
58
68
N
O
P
Q
123


111
90
110
130
150
R
S
T
U
126



Table 2:



cost_center
domain




123
workplace


125
PI


127
space


126
blockchain



Based on the condition (pseudo-code):
"if l3_mgr_id=badge then fetch the details of the field(l3_mgr_id,l3_mgr_name) corresponding to it,
if l4_mgr_id=badge then fetch the details corresponding to ite(l4_mgr_id,l4_mgr_name)."
For cost center need to find based on both input table for l3 and l4
Expected output:



l3_mgr_id
l3_mgr_name
l3_cost_center
l4_mgr_id
l4_mgr_name
l4_cost_center




666
G
PI
555
L
space


222
P
workspace
111
U
blockchain



I am not getting the expected output.
I have tried below query but it's giving me no results with above data:
select distinct 
                CASE WHEN t1.l3_mgr_id = t1.badge THEN t1.l3_mgr_id ELSE NULL END AS l3_mgr_id,
                CASE WHEN t1.l3_mgr_id = t1.badge THEN t1.l3_mgr_name ELSE NULL END AS   
                l3_mgr_name,
                CASE WHEN t1.l4_mgr_id = t1.badge THEN t1.l4_mgr_id ELSE NULL END AS l4_mgr_id,
                CASE WHEN t1.l4_mgr_id = t1.badge THEN t1.l4_mgr_name ELSE NULL END AS 
                l4_mgr_name,t2.cost_center FROM test t1
left join test t2
on t1.cost_center=t2.cost_center


Are you serious about the ancient Postgres version 9.4?

Note, your question works, but showing actual CREATE TABLE scripts and providing sample data as (properly formatted) INSERT scripts would be much better.

This produces your desired result:
SELECT t1.l3_mgr_id, l3.l3_mgr_name, l3c.domain AS l3_cost_center
     , t1.l4_mgr_id, l4.l4_mgr_name, l4c.domain AS l4_cost_center
FROM   t1
JOIN   t1      l3  ON l3.badge = t1.l3_mgr_id
LEFT   JOIN t2 l3c ON l3c.cost_center = l3.cost_center
JOIN   t1      l4  ON l4.badge = t1.l4_mgr_id
LEFT   JOIN t2 l4c ON l4c.cost_center = l4.cost_center;

fiddle
Your relational design and your ancient Postgres 9.4 don't seem ideal ..
